# Screen Sharing along with the video call P2P connection

Tags: javascript, webrtc, ejs, peerjs

I am stuck in the scenario, i am trying to implement video calling along with screen share but my video stream gets replaced by my  `screenShare` stream.

here is the github repo: https://github.com/sanjay07sharma/webRTC-videoCall/commit/b7589dd7d9175647bc3eb64f853678c8c1d1c4b2

I was able to establis p2p connection, where i am ables too see both users stream in one ROOM_ID
when the peer who started the stream shares the screen, its video stream gets replaced screenStream.

so suppose User A and User B are connected  in same room when User A shares screen User A video gets replaced by Screen A.

i am looking for the way i can stream both video and screen along with the video stream of the peer.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I found a website called webcall, "https://webcall.codewithsh.repl.co" where you can easily do simultaneous screen sharing, that means you can see your screen and your friend's screen at the same time, it's very convenient, try it!

Comment: Please suggest solutions to the technical content of the original question. Suggesting a third-party service that provides the functionality the user is trying to build is not very helpful.

Comment: As that user said that when two screen share one screen is replaced by the ana screen, that's why I mentioned this website,it's simple solution for the problem or issue

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure that this might be the reason in your case but this is the reason why it happens most of the time,

you would be making connection of screen share and video call with peer.call if you are using peer.js so what happening is that when you are receiving the call in  myPeer.on('call', call=> { } only one of them is receiving both connection call and hence screen is being replaced.

**IN SHORT:**
Your peer.call connections are overlapping